# how much storage space does linux take

Tags: linux, hard-drive, storage

Just wanted to download Linux. I'd like to know how much space it takes up before downloading it. Can anyone please give me a specific amount to nearest GB.

Comment: Your question is too broad... "Linux" is too generic, depending on the distro and options it could be less than 1GB to hundreds of gigs. Best bet, look at the system requirements for the distrobution you are interested in.

Comment: If you get one of the "tiny" linux distributions it can take only a few megabytes of storage. Fully loaded distributions could be tens of gigabytes for everything. No one can give you a specific amount because no one knows what you need or even what distribution.

Answer (score 2):

No - it depends entirely on what you're talking about.

- A binary kernel, is about 5-10 MB, depending on your system
- A compressed archive of the kernel sources is about 155 MB
- The complete git history of the kernel comes to about 2 GB (with files checked out)
- If, in fact, you're talking about a core distribution of Linux such as [Ubuntu Core for RaspberryPi 3](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/core/raspberry-pi-2-3), then you're looking at about 335 MB
- If you're after a 'server' / minimal release of a distribution, like [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), then it's around 770 MB
- If you're after a 'desktop' release of a distribution, like [Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), then it's around 1.5 GB

Bear in mind that for the distributions, there will likely be more packages downloaded from the internet that do not come packaged on the installation media, so even in this case, you won't get an up-to-date / full system for the stated figures.

Typically installation media for a desktop distribution will fit on a DVD (4.7 GB), with a basic installation consuming around 4-8 GB.

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that a typical distro is about 4 gigs which is a DVD worth, and that a typical base system with GUI and working environment - but not all apps - would want 4-8 gigs installed - although of-course it can be trimmed to a tiny fraction of this.